# pass function to another and call by name

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

```
<a id="aHw" href="#" callbackName="helloworld">test</a>
    ...
    <script>
      function helloworld() { alert('hello world'); }
    </script>
     ...
```

question ; how can i produce callBack to pass another function

```
    <script>
     ...
    var cbName = $('#aHw').attr('callbackName');

    foo( passfunction );  //How???
    ...
   </script>

    <script> 
    function foo(callBack)
    {
       callBack(); // call hello world.
    }
   </script>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So to have an anchor do something on MouseOver, you'd use this code:

```
<a id="aHw" href="#" onmouseover="doSomething()">test</a>
```

You can pass a function to another function this way:

```
function callSomeFunction( fn )
{
    fn();
}

callSomeFunction( alert );
```

Or you can pass an anonymous function to the above:

```
 callSomeFunction( function(){ alert( "Finally! A message!" ); } );
```

If you're trying to pass the name of a function as a string (which is a fundamentally bad idea and a terrible risk and hard to debug and ***DON'T DO IT***), then you can use eval:

```
function callNamedFunction( fn )
{
   eval(fn)()
}
```

Or you might be able to get away with:

```
function callNamedFunction( fn )
{
   (window[fn])()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A function in JavaScript is just an object.

The question(s) don't make terribly much sense to me, but consider the following:

```
function fn1 () {
    alert("fn1")
}

function doIt(cb) {
   cb()
}

// direct -- to show point in general
// fn1 evaluates to the function-object, which is then passed
doIt(fn1)

// lookups up fn1 by name, then passes that function-object
// the value "fn1" can be any arbitrary string, such as that which
// was stored in the attr:
//   e.g. doIt(window[cbName])
doIt(window["fn1"])

// anon function to iterate sameness
// the anon function returns a new function-object
doIt(function () { alert("anon") })
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo( Function('return ' + cbName)() )
```

I think that's what your after..

But if it's in the browser, and you know that the callback is a global object, you could do..

```
foo(window[cbName])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if nothing else helps, `eval()` will:

```
function foo( callBack ) {
 eval( callBack + '()' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the function is defined (e.g `window`, or custom namespace) you can invoke it by the string name. Otherwise you would have to `eval` (bad idea). Also, use `data-attributes`.

```
<a href="#" data-callback="helloworld">test</a>
```

...

```
// invoke runs a function by name in the provided context, or window
function invoke(cbname, context){
    return (context || window)[cbname].call();
}
// get attribute through the data method
var funcName = $('a').data('callback');

// run callback
var result = invoke(funcName);
```